# Perl WWW::Mechanize::Firefox POST() Implementation

Tags: perl

Can I get some help on how to submit a POST with the necessary variables using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?  I've installed all the perl modules, and the firefox plugin and tested such that I can connect to a give host and get responses...  my questions is how to submit a POST request.  On the documentation Corion says he may never implement. This seems odd, I'm hoping I can use the inherited nature from Mechanize, but can't find any examples.  A simple example would help me tremendously.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->allow( javascript =>1);                  # enable javascript

# http
$mech->get("http://www.example.com");
my $c = $mech->content;
```

Is there a mech->post() option I am simply missing?

many thanks in advance.

R

Comment: As the answers below state, the 'post' option is 'hidden' behind a form submission. Do you have a reason not to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get a page, fill out a form, submit the form

if you're going to be skipping the above steps by using post, you don't need mechanize firefox

Comment: I'm using firefox for its javascript engine because the site uses javascript fairly extensively for AJAX, setting cookies, redirection etc.  Is there another mechanize option with a sound javascript engine that can accomplish this which you'd suggest?

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would just set the fields and submit the form like this:

```
$mech->get('http://www.website.com');
$mech->submit_form(
      with_fields => {
          user => 'me',
          pass => 'secret',
      }
);
```

Comment: I will try this, but it seems unclear as to what the "action" for the form would be in the above example.  There is no <form> tag that a user is supposed to manually intervene, the site simply sends via POST with several variables which is why I'm thinking I need mech->post('www.site.com/updateVar', postvar1 => 'me', postvar2 => 'secret').

Comment: If it helps, I'm trying to replicate the behavior of using wget with the --post-data option to a URL directly.  Doesn't the submit_form function presume that the form action is stated in the html from the previous get and you tell mech to submit_form generating a POST request to the specific target of the form action attribute?

Comment: If you don't have a form on the site and just want to emulate curl/wget, I suggest looking at LWP::UserAgent which comes with a plain post method: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.03/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

Comment: Actually the reason I'm not using curl/wget is because of the lack of javascript support.  After looking around there appear to be some decent initial attempts at adding a javascript engine to Mechanize...I'll try them and see. Thx.